# Visual Studio 2012 installing nuget offline

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, offline

I tried installing some .net packages in an internal server when some of them failed saying that I should upgrade nuget. I uninstalled nuget package manager.

Since the server is offline I just set up a local package source when I needed packages, but now when I need to install nuget manager it self I cant seem to be able to outside of visual studio, which requires internet access.

I do have the ability to move files to the server since I am using a sort of remote access connection that allows coping of files. Can I install nuget that way or must I open the server to the download link?

Comment: We don't put "solved" in the question.  Just accept your answer and that's good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got this embarrassingly quickly. All I had to do was to go to the visual studio gallery and to download the right nuget VSIX file for visual studio 2012 and then just run it...

It was asked before here:
https://superuser.com/questions/73675/how-do-i-install-a-vsix-file-in-visual-studio